# Mongoose limit query for more performance

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to load huge data and it takes so much time. 
On frontend I am displaying first 5 data. But I think I have to to it on backend side as well.

I want to click on button then it should appear the next 5 objects. In this case on frontend with Angular its working but I will do it also in backend site.

How can I sent to backend to load the next 5 object(records). 
Thank for your help in advance.

**Node.js**

```
router.get('/load', function(req, res) {

    Experiences.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, docs_accommo) {

        res.send(docs_accommo);


    });

});
```

**Angular.js**

```
app.controller('loadData', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$upload', '$rootScope',
function($scope, $http, $window, $upload, $rootScope) {
$http.get('/load').success(function(data) {

        $scope.datafront = data;
    });

$scope.totalDisplayed = 5;

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        $scope.totalDisplayed += 5;
    };

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div  ng-repeat="x in datafront | limitTo:totalDisplayed track by x._id" ng-cloak>
{{x}}

</div>


<button   class="btn btn-default" ng-click="loadMore()" style="float:right; margin-bottom:20px;" onClick="nanobar.go(100)">
```

Load more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
router.get('/load', function(req, res) {

    var skip = req.query.skip || 0;
    var limit = req.query.limit || 50;

    Experiences
        .find()
        .lean()
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit)
        .exec(function(err, docs_accommo) {

            res.send(docs_accommo);


    });

});
```

Angular:

```
app.controller('loadData', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$upload', '$rootScope',
function($scope, $http, $window, $upload, $rootScope) {
    $scope.datafront = [];

    function loadMore() {
        $http.get('/load',
                 {params: {limit: 5, skip: $scope.datafront.length}})
        .success(function(data) {

            $scope.datafront = $scope.datafront.concat(data);
        });
    }

    loadMore();


    $scope.loadMore = loadMore;

});
```

Comment: Many thanks. Can brief explain how its works wth skip and limit?

Comment: Sure. On each request you provide mongo with numbers of records to skip and limit num to. Say you want to load by 5 (as in your original post), so pass `limit: 5`. And a number to skip is the current number of already displayed items, so `skip: $scope.datafront.length`. After each request items are concatenated with already loaded ones.

Comment: Ok I have implement it but how the html will look like? In case of my example? I am not getting data

Comment: Get rid of `| limitTo:totalDisplayed`

Comment: nope, I think the param is not working. After deleting it the data is rendering but the loadMore() Button is not incrementing.

Comment: Hello svlapin, I have one more question to your solution. Is there any opportunity to pass data from html ng-model via $scope?

Comment: If you have smth like `$scope.smth = 'Text here';` in your controller code, you can use eg `<input type="text" ng-model="smth">` in your html (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: yes I mean something like that. But if the value is changed at input field or select option the value will within controller will also change immediately? Many thanx